# ZFDebug no debug bar

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using ZF1 and just installed ZFDebug, however, there is no debug window when I enter the website. Here is the function I use to init ZFDebug

```
protected function _initZFDebug()
    {
        if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'testing')
        {
            $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
            if ($auth->hasIdentity())
            {
                $identity = $auth->getIdentity();
                if ($identity->getRole() == 'admin')
                {
                $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
                $autoloader->registerNamespace('ZFDebug_');

                $options = array(
                'plugins' => array(
                            'Variables',
                            'Database' => array(
                                'adapter' => Zend_Registry::get('db')
                            ),
                            'File' => array(
                                'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH
                            ),
                            'Cache' => array(
                                'backend' => Zend_Registry::get('Cache')->getBackend()
                            ),
                            'Exception'
                        )
                );
                $debug = new ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_Debug($options);
                $this->bootstrap('frontController');
                $frontController = $this->getResource('frontController');
                $frontController->registerPlugin($debug);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging to see if you're getting inside all three of your `if` blocks?

Comment: I did and indeed every piece of code is reached, variables are also set and not empty/null